# Collapse duplicate rows by median value in R

Tags: r

I have a date frame with two columns.  I would like to remove rows where there are duplicate entries in the first column.  however I would like to select a specific row to remain based on the value of the second columns.

Specifically - if there are 2 duplicate entries in columns 1, I would like the row removed with the lower value in column 2

Or if there are more than 2 identical entries in columns 1 then I would like the row with the median value in row 2 to remain.

So for data frame

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",1), rep("D",1), rep("D",1))
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,7,6)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

would become

```
a <- c(rep("A", 1), rep("B", 1), rep("C",1), rep("D",1))
b <- c(2,5,4,7)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

I have tried functions unique() and duplicated() but can't seem to find arguments that meet these criteria.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: For base R, you can also have a look at `?aggregate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(b = ifelse(n() == 2, min(b), median(b)))

  a b
1 A 2
2 B 5
3 C 4
4 D 6
```

In your question, you said you want the "lower" value, in case there are two rows, which would give D=6, rather than D=7. If you meant the first row that appears in the data frame, you can do this:

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(b = ifelse(n() == 2, b[1], median(b)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(b=if(.N==2) min(b) else median(b)) , by = a]
#   a b
#1: A 2
#2: B 5
#3: C 4
#4: D 6
```

Or a similar option with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(b~a, df, FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==2) min(x) else median(x))
#  a b
#1 A 2
#2 B 5
#3 C 4
#4 D 6
```

Or

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select a, 
        case
          when count(b) is 2 then min(b)
          else median(b)
         end b 
       from df
       group by a')
 #  a b
 #1 A 2
 #2 B 5
 #3 C 4
 #4 D 6
```

Based on the expected output showed, the last row is `D 7`, so if we are selecting the first observation when the group length is 2,

```
 setDT(df)[, list(b=if(.N==2) b[1L] else median(b)) , by = a]
 #   a b
 #1: A 2
 #2: B 5
 #3: C 4
 #4: D 7
```

Or

```
 aggregate(b~a, df, FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==2) x[1L] else median(x))
 #  a b
 #1 A 2
 #2 B 5
 #3 C 4
 #4 D 7
```

Or

```
 sqldf('select a,
           case 
             when count(b) is 2 and min(rowid) then b
             else median(b)
           end b
         from df
       group by a')
 #  a b
 #1 A 2
 #2 B 5
 #3 C 4
 #4 D 7
```

**EDIT** changed first observation to `min` after I saw @eipi10's post.  Didn't read the OP's post correctly and the OP's expected output is not matching the description.